# Command npm not working on copied projects in MAC OS . code: ENOENT

Tags: macos, vue.js, npm, node-modules

I'm new to Mac OS ecosystem, and I'm porting some projects from other computers to the Macbook.

I have several projects that use npm packages, Mainly Laravel / Vue Projects.

When I create a new project it works, I'm able to run all type of npm commands, but if it is a copy and pasted project from another pc it does not work.

I already tried everything that if could find (reinstall , using sudo, follow youtube tutorials on how to install, changing folder permissions and more) it still doesn't work.

I get the following error :

```
node:events:304
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js',
  path: 'node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js',
  spawnargs: [
    '--progress',
    '--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js',
    '--watch'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/user/Documents/Dev/projects/laravel-vue
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2020-12-19T19_30_29_021Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/user/Documents/Dev/projects/laravel-vue
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npm run development -- --watch

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2020-12-19T19_30_29_046Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are the computers from which the files are copied from also Macs? It's possible that some commands in package.json or something else are specific to a different OS and thus don't run properly when copied over.

Comment: The file is the same.